# Forming orthogonal bases in different orders

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$ be unit vectors in some vector space $V = R^d$. For any permutation $\pi: [n] \rightarrow [n]$, we can form the Gram-Schmidt orthogonal bases $\beta_{\pi,1}, \dots, \beta_{\pi,n}$ as 
$\beta_{\pi, 1} = \alpha_{\pi(1)}, \beta_{\pi,2} = \alpha_{\pi(2)} - (\alpha_{\pi(2)} . \beta_{\pi,1}) \beta_{\pi,1}$ etc.

Now, for any permutation $\pi$ define the set $X_{\pi} = \{ x \in V \mid (x.\beta_{\pi,i})^2 \geq \lambda \text{ for $i = 1, \dots, n$} \}$.

And define the set $X = \cup_{\pi} X_{\pi}$.

What does this set look like? Can one bound its volume?

Obviously, you can sum the volume of $X_{\pi}$ over $\pi \in S_n$. However, intuitively, it seems that the worst case for the volume of $X_{\pi}$ would be when the $\alpha$ vectors are orthonormal --- otherwise, the $\beta$ vectors become smaller. But in that case, $X_{\pi}$ does not depend on $\pi$ at all. So it seems like you should be able to avoid this extra factor of $n!$

Comment: What do you mean by $x.\beta^\pi_i$? The $i$th component of $x$ with respect to the orthogonal basis?

Comment: @Andres, I mean the inner product.

Comment: You probably meant $\leq$ rather than $\geq$ in the definition of $X_\pi$.

Comment: @Mariano, no I mean $\geq$. It's not as nice geometrically I know.

Comment: But then $X_\pi$ is the complement of a parallelopiped, which has infinite volume.

Comment: BTW: friends do not let friends use `\cup` where they meant `\bigcup`!

Comment: @Mariano, I wanted to know about the Gaussian volume. But, I also wanted to know what the "shape" of $X$ was without reference to a specific measure.

Comment: You should then probably be explicit about what you want in the body of the question!

Comment: @ Mariano, probably you are right. But I have also been frustrated when I ask too specific a question and get too specific an answer.

Comment: How $d$ and $n$ are related? $n\le d$?

Comment: @ Sasha. $d$ is irrelevant (I think). You can probably assume $n \leq d$.

Comment: @DavidHarris, but here is not a problem of specificity. As statemnt, there is no hint that you want something which is not the Euclidean volume of things, and the Euclidean volume is not finite!